# Button selections displayed in table

Tags: javascript, html, button, html-table

I am trying to get my button selections to display in a table on my web application. Bellow you find the pieces of code that relate to my 1. My function which allows for the selections (may not even be relevant..), 2. the buttons which you can select in order to set the parameters, and 3 the table with class name and the rows where they will go. I've been struggling with this! Please Help!

My function:

```
function setClip(val) 
{
clip=val;
}

function setZoom(val) 
{
zoom=val;
}

function geoMap(val)
{
gmap=val;
}

function swap(imgNumber)
{
if(clip==true & zoom==false & gmap==false)
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+"clip.jpg";

else if(clip==false & zoom==true & gmap==false) 
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+"zoom.jpg";

else if(clip==false & zoom==true & gmap==true)
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+"zoomp.jpg";

else if(clip==true & zoom==true & gmap==true)
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+"clipzoomp.jpg";

else if(clip==true & zoom==false & gmap==true)
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+"clipp.jpg";

else if(clip==true & zoom==true & gmap==false)
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+"clipzoom.jpg"; 

else if(clip==false & zoom==false & gmap==true)
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+"p.jpg";

else
document.getElementById("default").src=imgNumber+".jpg";

}
```

My Buttons:

```
<input type ="button" id="button3" value="Apply Mask" onclick="setClip(true)">
<input type ="button" id="button3" value="No Mask" onclick="setClip(false)">
<input type="button" id="button3" value="Maintain Zoom In" onClick="setZoom(true)"> 
<input type="button" id="button3"value="Maintain Full View" onClick="setZoom(false)">
<input type="button" id="button3" value="GeoMap On" onClick="geoMap(true)">
<input type="button" id="button3" value="GeoMap Off" onClick="geoMap(false)">
```

The table I would like my selections to be displayed in, basically I want the values of the selected buttons to but put in the table after they have been selected

```
<table class="status" height="50" width="800">
<tr>
    <td  width="200" align="center">Step 1 Selection</td>
    <td  width="200" align="center">Step 2 Selection</td>
        <td  width="200" align="center">Step 3 Selection</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: instead of  if(clip==true & zoom==false & gmap==false) just write it if(clip & !zoom & !gmap) make it cleaner

Comment: while & does work here you should use &&

Comment: The issue is I want my selections to be displayed where you see step 1 selection, step 2 selection, step 3 selection. As per the javascript code, I'm brand new at this.. uphill battle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet here is using jQuery. It's far easier to manipulate than Javascript and was designed to easily manipulate objects. If you know CSS and a little Javascript, it's easy to pick up too. You don't even have to host it, as Google hosts it. All you need to do is add the following source code to the top where your scripts are:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var buttonCount=1;
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
        if(buttonCount <= 3) {
            //make sure that there are no duplicates
            if($(this).get(0).className != "buttonUsed")
            {
                $(this).get(0).className = "buttonUsed";

                var htmlString = $(this).attr('value');
                $('#sel' + buttonCount).html(htmlString);

                buttonCount++;
            }
        }
    });
});
... The rest of your script
```

I notice that you have been using IDs like one might use classes. I would advise you to consider using the class attribute for things like "button" and make IDs more unique. It will make it easier to code with Javascript, as JS usually follows IDs and works best if it targets only one element per ID. In any case I did rename your IDs. If you have CSS you can rename your CSS classes. Just note that in my code I renamed a class so that you can't choose more than one. That might work for you anyway, because then your button that has been used can look different from the unused buttons.

Anyway, here is the HTML, adapted:

```
<table class="status" id="buttonStatus" height="50" width="800">
<tr>
    <td  width="200" align="center">Step 1 Selection</td>
    <td  width="200" align="center">Step 2 Selection</td>
        <td  width="200" align="center">Step 3 Selection</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td width="200" align="center" id="sel1"> </td>
    <td width="200" align="center" id="sel2"> </td>
    <td width="200" align="center" id="sel3"> </td>
</tr>   
</table>
</body>
```

Let me know if this works.

### Update

To edit as you desire, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
        //make sure that there are no duplicates
        var buttonClassName = $(this).get(0).className;
        if(buttonClassName != "buttonUsed")
        {
            var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
            var firstPart = buttonID.substring(0,6);
            var secondPart = buttonID.substring(6,7);
            var thirdPart = buttonID.substring(7);


            var newThirdPart;
            switch(thirdPart) 
            {
                case "a"    :   newThirdPart = "b"; break;
                case "b"    :   newThirdPart = "a"; break;
            }
            $(this).get(0).className = "buttonUsed";
            $("#" + firstPart + secondPart + newThirdPart).get(0).className = "button";



            var htmlString = $(this).attr('value');
            $('#sel' + secondPart).html(htmlString);
        }
    });
});
```

### And the HTML

```
<body>
<input type ="button" class="button" id="button1a" value="Apply Mask" onclick="setClip(true)">
<input type ="button" class="button" id="button1b" value="No Mask" onclick="setClip(false)">
<input type="button" class="button" id="button2a" value="Maintain Zoom In" onClick="setZoom(true)"> 
<input type="button" class="button" id="button2b"value="Maintain Full View" onClick="setZoom(false)">
<input type="button" class="button" id="button3a" value="GeoMap On" onClick="geoMap(true)">
<input type="button" class="button" id="button3b" value="GeoMap Off" onClick="geoMap(false)"><BR><BR><BR>

<table class="status" id="buttonStatus" height="50" width="800">
<tr>
    <td  width="200" align="center">Step 1 Selection</td>
    <td  width="200" align="center">Step 2 Selection</td>
        <td  width="200" align="center">Step 3 Selection</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td width="200" align="center" id="sel1"> </td>
    <td width="200" align="center" id="sel2"> </td>
    <td width="200" align="center" id="sel3"> </td>
</tr>   
</table>
</body>
```

### Note on CSS

This JQuery changes the classname of the active button to buttonUsed, which means you can create a CSS to make the button look highlighted. If you'd rather not do that, and would rather have everything stay as button, you don't actually need it in the new example (whereas in my initial stab at it, it was very necessary).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
        //make sure that there are no duplicates

        var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
        var secondPart = buttonID.substring(6,7);


        var htmlString = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#sel' + secondPart).html(htmlString);
    });
});
```

Much simpler, in fact. At least I showed you the sort of things jQuery is capable of. Whether you choose to use it or not is up to you. Happy coding!

Comment: I just noticed a small issue with the code. It work's well for the first three selections, but if you go back and click a different button it will not change in the cell. It will only display the first three initial selections. How do you make it more dynamic so that it changes on the fly??

Comment: Also the first cell can only display either Apply Mask or No Mask, while the second cell will have only Maintain Zoom In or Maintain Full View. In this instance if you click Apply Mask then No Mask, it will put first in the first cell and the second in the second cell. So basically I need each of the respective cells to portray on the fly the selections from step 1 step 2 and step 3

Comment: Are you talking about adding more rows? More columns? Going back to the first column? Or cycling so that the old column 1/2 becomes the new column 2/3 and the new column becomes 1? If I get that clarification I can explain further.

Comment: I wish had enough reputation to show an image of my app. first three steps: Picture as follows

So the brackets are buttons (button)
Step 1 (Apply Mask)(No Mask)
Step 2 (Maintain Zoom In) (Maintain Full View)
Step 3(GeoMap On) (GeoMap Off)

Once an option from each step is chosen you can select another button which loads an image based on the paramters chosen in each step. In a table with three cells I need the parameters chose to show so picture the first cell | param 1 | param 2 | param 3 |. If you go back and switch a parameter, I need the display in the cell to update

Comment: I can send you a picture of the app via email ?

Comment: when you say make sure there are no duplicates, do you mean for me to go back and alter the id's of the buttons so that each one has it's own respective id's?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add the body. Now added. You will need unique identifiers but I changed those when I updated the script. If that doesn't work let me know and we can talk about images.

Comment: No prob! Happy to be of service.

Comment: I re-named a class so that you can't click on it again. I would advise you to either get rid of that class code or, and this is my preference, add a new styling for buttonUsed. That way the user sees that that button has been used. It looks a little fresher as you can highlight it so it looks selected. It will update whenever you change the button. If you don't want that the thing you'll need to get rid of any reference to buttonUsed class naming. I don't think you actually need it anymore.

Comment: perfect, so I have this for my styling: 

    .buttonUsed
  {
  background-color:red;
  color:#FFF8EB;
  padding:7px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  width: 125px
  } 

When i click the button it changes, but the other one then looses its css, the non selected button, does it have a class name?

Comment: take a look at whatever you choose to call your class name. The code  $("#" + firstPart + secondPart + newThirdPart).get(0).className = "button" declares the className to be .button. If you have it as .button3, you want to change that line of code so the className = button3, or whatever it is called.